# notes and attachment not appearing account

Tags: account

In my accounts, I can see files but not notes and attachments.
In my other environment I can see it.
Where is the setting to make it appear ? In layout I cannot see it either

With my apex class I am doing insert attachment with the parentID equal to the accountid.

Unfortunately because notes and attachments are not there, I cannot see my file (the insert).

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right way. You just need to switch to the **Related Lists** and drag **Notes & Attachments** to layout.
[image]

Also make sure you are adding the related list to the proper layout.

Comment: You are a savior ;) I will accept your answer as soon as the time limit is done